# newenvironment and chemfig

Tags: environments, chemfig, tags

Since can't set a label to a chemical reaction with `chemfig` package, the only solution is put the scheme between `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`

```
\begin{equation}
\schemestart
2 \ce{H_{2}O} \arrow{<=>} \ce{H_{3}O^{+}} \+ \ce{OH^{-}}
\schemestop
\end{equation}
```

And this, works fine.
So, I think to create a new newenvironment called "reaction": this is my attempt

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\newenvironment{reaction}
    {
    \centering
    \begin{equation}
    \schemestart
    \schemestop
    \end{equation}
    }

\begin{document}

    \begin{reaction}
    2 \ce{H_{2}O} \arrow{<=>} \ce{H_{3}O^{+}} \+ \ce{OH^{-}}
    \end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

This is the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence. 2 \ce{H_{2}O} \arrow
```

Seems like `\arrow` sequence not works on reaction environment

How can I improve the new environment?

Comment: unrelated to your question but `\centering` has no effect on equations.  Your `\newenvironemnt`is missing the third argument with the end code, I assume you intended `}` after `\schemestart` and `{` before `\schemestop`  so the environment body goes between those?

Comment: Yes, I  intend to put my `\newenvironemnt` content between `\schemestart` and `\schemestop`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a final argument to `\newenvironment` (picking up the blank line so avoiding an error) so your equation is always empty and the environment content is following that.

[image]

The chemistry macros don't appear to like a normal newenvironment so using xparse here to grab the environment body

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{reaction}{b}
    {%
    \begin{equation}%
    \schemestart
     #1
    \schemestop
    \end{equation}%
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
    2 \ce{H_{2}O} \arrow{<=>} \ce{H_{3}O^{+}} \+ \ce{OH^{-}}
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!